# How to remove focus from control when window does not have focus?(otherwise it will be restored when window gains focus again)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, focusmanager

I need to remove focus from `TextInput` while `Adobe Air` window does not have focus. But I can't find *normal* way to do this.

Here is a sample app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

                       >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function onFocusIn(event:FocusEvent):void{
                input.appendText('I');
            }

            protected function onFocusOut(event:FocusEvent):void{
                input.appendText('o');
            //  input.focusManager.deactivate();
            //  stage.focus = null;  
            //  focusManager.setFocus(input2);
            //  stage.focus = stage; 
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:VGroup>      
        <s:TextInput id="input" focusIn="onFocusIn(event)" focusOut="onFocusOut(event)" />
        <s:TextInput id="input2" /> 
    </s:VGroup>
```

1. `stage.focus = null` does not work - `stage.focus` is already `null` when window does not have focus, so it does not work.
2. `input.focusManager.deativate()` does the trick, but it seems that this manager is used for other controls, so this is not a good option. It is said in the documentation that

   > The SystemManager activates and deactivates a FocusManager if more
   >   than one IFocusManagerContainer is visible at the same time.

   but in this sample app I have two TextInputs and when I deactivate focusManager for first one, second one does not restore focus on alt-tab any more.
3. I can set focus to something else, but creating special 'dummy' input is some kind of monkey patch, and I prefer to avoid using it until it is inescapable.
4. Setting `stage.focus` to some parent of TextInput does not have any effect either.

   **So, do you know any better way to remove focus from component while window does not have focus?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution that satisfies me:

`FocusManager(focusManager).mx_internal::lastFocus = null;`

It's not perfect as it uses mx_internal namespace property which can be changed in future sdk releases.

This solution works because focus is restored by FocusManager on windows activation(nice code with commented out lines...):

```
    private function activateWindowHandler(event:Event):void
    {
//        var target:InteractiveObject = InteractiveObject(event.target);
        // trace("FM " + this + " activateWindowHandler ", _lastFocus);

        windowActivated = true;

        if (activated)
        {
            dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.FLEX_WINDOW_ACTIVATE));
            // restore focus if this focus manager had last focus
            if (_lastFocus && !browserMode)
                _lastFocus.setFocus();
            lastAction = "ACTIVATE";
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately is not a part of `focusIn` handler stack trace, so it took time to find who is restoring focus on windows activation.